# StencilJS - Updating the state causing whole component to re-render

Tags: components, state, stenciljs, rerender

In StencilJS, i am trying to re-render only the updated value of state. But each time, when value updates, whole component is getting re-render. Is there any solution to avoid this?

Below is the code:

```
@State() visible = true 

handleRetryClick = () => {
  this.visible = false;
};

render() {
      return (
        <div class={this.visible ? "modal-wrapper" : "modal-close"}>
          <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-container">
              <div class="title">{this.status}</div>
              <div class="button-container">
                <button class="retry" onClick={this.handleRetryClick}>{this.modalButtonLabel}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the purpose of a state-decorated property that when its value changes the component re-renders. See https://stenciljs.com/docs/state:

> Any changes to a `@State()` property will cause the components render function to be called again.

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you're worried that all elements inside your component get re-drawn by the browser, then that's not exactly the case. Stencil's runtime uses a virtual DOM, i. e. when the component re-renders, it compares the previous and new DOM nodes and generates a diff, and only the elements with differences will be modified in the real DOM.